# jQuery remove delay blink effect with event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I actually use some mouseenter & mouseleave event to add a button (which is not actually a button) to a `<li>`.

But, there is a problem with my code.. The button appear and remove on mouseleave & mouseenter, but, when I hover the button, it disappear and it create a big blink effect.

This is a normal situation because it leave my title (which is the tag where the event is called).

To solve this problem, i tried to add a timeout, for keep the button 1sec more even if i leave the title.

But, it didn't work, with this solution, the button don't disappear.

Here is the jQuery code which add the button (the timeout is actually commented)

```
$("ul").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        if($(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').length===0){
            $(this).parent().append("<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/office/256/edit-icon.png' class='imgEdit' width='20px' height='20px'></img>");
            $(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').css('position', 'absolute');
            $(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').css('left', $(this).parent().width() - 30);
            $(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').css('top', '30px');
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
     //setTimeout(function(){
           $(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').remove(); 
      // },200);
    }
}, ".titre");
```

And here is a fiddle of the global code:

http://jsfiddle.net/7MJ5V/

Comment: Ur fiddle is working ,button hides when mouse leave ,whats the problem?

Comment: I don't want that the button disappear if I hover it. And actually, if i hover it, it start to blink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a CSS only solution.

See that : http://jsfiddle.net/7MJ5V/2/

You should hide your image by default, and then show it on hover the title. Here is the CSS :

```
ul .titre:hover .imgEdit {
    display: inline-block;
}

.imgEdit {
    display: none;
    right: 2px;
    top: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending img out of div.titre . Thats why mouse leave is triggered when you hover on image

Replace

```
   $(this).parent().append("<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/office/256/edit-icon.png' class='imgEdit' width='20px' height='20px'></img>");
```

with

```
   $(this).append("<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/office/256/edit-icon.png' class='imgEdit' width='20px' height='20px'></img>");
```

[FIXED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/7MJ5V/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use .hover function instead of using mouseenter and mouseleave.
Or use mouseover and mouseout function.

Comment: It don't change the problem. Even if i use mouseout & mousehover, when i hover the button, i don't hover the title.. And the button continue to blink.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7MJ5V/3/)

Check this code:

```
$("ul").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        if($(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').length===0){
            $(this).parent().append("<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/office/256/edit-icon.png' class='imgEdit' width='20px' height='20px' ></img>");
            $(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').css('position', 'absolute');
            $(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').css('z-index', '-1');
            $(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').css('left', $(this).parent().width() - 30);
            $(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').css('top', '30px');
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
     //setTimeout(function(){
           $(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').remove(); 
      // },200);
    }
}, ".titre");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  Is didn't see the fiddle.
What you can do is, instead of adding an  tag.  You can add it as background image.  In this way, the mouseleave or mouseout won't trigger when your mouse will go over the image.  On mouseleave you can set background as "none".
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a CSS solution if you can.
However the problem does seem to be a z-indexing issue from what I can see in my developer console.

Try and add to your css:

```
.imgEdit {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

That should fix the issue. While your at it, you can move some of the other javascript too. Your code should look like this:

**Js:**

```
$("ul").on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    if ($(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').length === 0) {
      $(this).parent().append("<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/office/256/edit-icon.png' class='imgEdit' width='20px' height='20px'></img>");
      $(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').css('left', $(this).parent().width() - 30);
    }
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.imgEdit').remove(); 
  }
}, ".titre");
```

**css:**

```
.imgEdit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```